# Rename certain files recursively in a directory - Shell/Bash script

Tags: bash, shell, directory, rename

I've searched about everywhere, to come up with this script below. I can't figure out what the issue is here. 
I'm trying to loop through all the directories inside a directory called Extracted_Source to rename any files that is a CSV with an appended timestamp. 
Any help is appreciated.

I keep getting a

```
No such file or directory./Extracted_Source/*
```

Below is the source:

```
for files in ./Extracted_Source/*
do if ["$files" contains ".csv"]
then mv "$files" "${files%}_$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S").csv";
fi done; echo end
```

Comment: This means that either the folder `Extracted_Source` doesn't exist within your current working directory, or `Extracted_Source/` doesn't contain any files. What does `ls ./Extracted_Source/*` show? I imagine it would be the same thing.

Comment: Your *parameter expansion w/substring removal* `${files%}` removes **nothing**. Perhaps you intended `${files%.csv}_...` ?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `find`

```
find ./Extracted_Source -type f -name "*.csv" | while -r read files; do mv "$files" "${files%.*}_$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S").csv"; done
```

This also has the added benefit of handling files containing spaces in the file name.

Here's the same thing in multi-line form:

```
find ./Extracted_Source -type f -name "*.csv" | \
while read -r files; do 
    mv "$files" "${files%.*}_$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S").csv"
done
```

You can also use process substitution to feed the `while` loop:

```
while read -r files; do 
    mv "$files" "${files%.*}_$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S").csv"
done < <(find ./Extracted_Source -type f -name "*.csv")
```

In your current script, `${files%}` is not doing anything. The `.csv` part of the file is not being removed. The correct way is `${files%.*}`.

Try this to see for yourself: `for files in *; do echo "${files%.*}"; done`

See the [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#common_use) for more info on this.

Comment: You are covered with `-name "*.csv"`, but it may be better to explicitly show what is being removed with the *substring removal*, e.g. `${files%.csv}_...` rather than `${files%.*}_`. Nothing wrong with the way you've done it, it's just a potential clarification. Also, since it is tagged `bash`, you can use *process substitution* to feed the `while` loop, e.g. `while read -r files; do ... done < <(find ./Extracted_Source -type f -name "*.csv")`

Answer (score 0):

For a start, the error message means that you don't have any files or folders in `./Extracted_Source/`. However, the following will work:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in ./Extracted_Source/*/*.csv; do
    mv "$file" "${file/.csv}_$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S").csv";
done

echo end
```

This doesn't account for csv files which have already been moved.

Comment: this doesn't rename the files which are inside directories inside `Extracted_Source`, which is the intention of the question.

Comment: Thanks @odradek - I've updated my answer and I have removed the unnecessary `if` statement.